# How to compare all the IDs of <li> with an array of javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have an array like the following:

```
aVN = new Array();
aVN.push(new Array('CET', 'July', 'Birthday',    '20110704'));
aVN.push(new Array('CGT', 'July', 'Anniversary', '20110705'));
```

I also have multiple `<li>` elements in my html like this:

```
<li id="thismonth">
   <ul>
      <li id="20110701">1</li>
      <li id="20110702">2</li>
      <li id="20110703">3</li>
      <li id="20110704" onclick="displayevent();" class="holiday">4</li>
      <li id="20110705">5</li>
   </ul>
```

I want to check whether `20110704` from the array `aVN` is present in the IDs of the `<li>`s.

If the ID and the array value match, then I want to display "Birthday" (the text from the array) when I click on that particular `<li>`.

Comment: [Don't create arrays like that.](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_Javascript_Arrays#quickIDX1)

Comment: So you essentially want to get all of the `<li>` elements, loop through each one and examine its `id` to see if it matches the condition, and then do something to the element that matches?

Comment: Element IDs can't start with a number. They must begin with a letter.

Comment: @damon in HTML5, this restriction is lifted.

Comment: @Matt: That's great; doesn't mean we should start piling out code with strictly numeric IDs, though. Not just yet anyway.

Comment: @Matt, interesting.. hadn't notice that.. thanks for the heads up..

Comment: @Matt: I didn't know that, thanks! Apparently, you can even use unicode! <p id="♥">

Comment: @damon what makes you think you're _not_ using unicode with alphanumeric characters?

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var aVN = [
    ['CET', 'July', 'Birthday',    '20110704'],
    ['CGT', 'July', 'Anniversary', '20110705']
];

function displayEvent(text) { // I'm not sure what you wanted to do here
    console.log(text);
}

$(function() {
   $('li.menu').click(function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < aVN.length; i++) {
          if (this.id == 'menu_' + aVN[i][3]) {
             displayEvent(aVN[i][2]);
          }
      }
   }).css({cursor: 'pointer'});
});
</script>

<ul>
   <li class="menu" id="menu_20110701">1</li>
   <li class="menu" id="menu_20110702">2</li>
   <li class="menu" id="menu_20110703">3</li>
   <li class="menu" id="menu_20110704">4</li>
   <li class="menu" id="menu_20110705">5</li>
</ul>
```

### [Live demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/QRDxm/)

<sup>(Thanks to Damon for pointing out that IDs may not start with a numeric character.)</sup>

Comment: That's just not true in HTML5.

Comment: @Matt: Not everybody is using HTML5.

Comment: Hmm, there's an issue with the closure here.

Comment: Fixed it by inverting the lookup.

Comment: this is what i wanna do...I have made a calendar..each day is made up of <li>'s...like the example above...Now my main aim is to check if the date in the array matches the date id of the <li>....if it matches (for example if "20110705" from the array matches the <li> with id "menu_20110705") then the color of that <li> should change and the other data from the array i.e: birthday should be displayed on mousehover

Comment: @user550884: Yes, I think we all got that. Instead of repeating your question, why not tell us the way in which the presented answers are not what you wanted?

Comment: @Tomalak : Sorry if i offended you...i didnt mean to repeat the question...Just wanted to phrase it properly..

Comment: @user550884: Offence is not the same as frustration. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
aVN = new Array();
aVN.push(new Array('CET', 'July','Birthday', '20110704'));
aVN.push(new Array('CGT', 'July','Anniversary', '20110705'));

for(var i = 0;i<avN.length;i++){
   if($("#"+avN[i][3]).length){
      $("#"+avN[i][3]).click(function(){
         alert(avN[i][2]);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You have syntax errors, and you're using a poor method of creating arrays.

Comment: this is what i wanna do...I have made a calendar..each day is made up of <li>'s...like the example above...Now my main aim is to check if the date in the array matches the date id of the <li>....if it matches (for example if "20110705" from the array matches the <li> with id "menu_20110705") then the color of that <li> should change and the other data from the array i.e: birthday should be displayed on mousehover

Comment: this is what i wanna do...I have made a calendar..each day is made up of <li>'s...like the example above...Now my main aim is to check if the date in the array matches the date id of the <li>....if it matches (for example if "20110705" from the array matches the <li> with id "menu_20110705") then the color of that <li> should change and the other data from the array i.e: birthday should be displayed on mousehover

Answer (score 0):

More "jquerysh" approach would be setting some class with common prefix and unique postfix (.allineed-1, .allineed-2 etc) and then finding content using appropriate css selector - `$(document.body).find(".allineed-" + id)`. Nevertheless, if you insist, you can use ids the same way.

Besides, not sure, but looks like you'd better keep a hash instead of array, since ids are unique (if we do not care about ordering). It would be a bit easier to perform inverse action - to map lis for some data. Keeping in mind that, again, there are some more "jquerysh" approaches - using data to associate dom object with some, well, data )))

Comment: Why would you ever use `$(document.body).find(".allineed-" + id)` instead of `$(".allineed-" + id)`?

Comment: @Matt Ball - just to illustrate that we can pass context.

Comment: this is what i wanna do...I have made a calendar..each day is made up of <li>'s...like the example above...Now my main aim is to check if the date in the array matches the date id of the <li>....if it matches (for example if "20110705" from the array matches the <li> with id "menu_20110705") then the color of that <li> should change and the other data from the array i.e: birthday should be displayed on mousehover